# How can I add a fadeIn effect to a string in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I've got the following string that increments my integer contained within a paragraph, and I'd like to append the fadeIn() jQuery function to it. I've tried to concatenate it to the end of the string, but that didn't work. Any suggestions on what to do here?

> ```
>                 $p.text(parseInt($p.text(),10) + 1);
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$p.text(parseInt($p.text(),10) + 1).hide().fadeIn();
```

Comment: +1 for first post and correct.  Here's a fiddle to go along with this http://jsfiddle.net/GKAJj/1/

Comment: @mdmullinax Haha nice one! I'd vote for your code if you had an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `$p.text(parseInt($p.text(),10) + 1).hide().fadeIn();`

Comment: What is telling you that `$p` corresponds to `$('p')`?

Comment: Thanks! You and Sly both gave me the correct answer. Gonna accept his since he beat you by a minute though. Have an upvote, though. :)               @ Haochi, I'm using `.find("p:first");` in my success function to make sure it only updates a specific one.

Comment: @Sly nothing, didn't copy/paste and habit of typing it that way = typo :\

Comment: @Laxman13 I was actually replying to Haochi :) Sorry for the confusion.